# Why is loop in my VBA code aggregating data?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have VBA code that copies data from one sheet and pastes into a new sheet. The code should loop through each row in the target sheet and paste data if the unique identifiers match. The pasted data in the first row is correct. However, in each consecutive row the data is aggregated

Eg: 
**Current output**

Row 1 - test1

Row 2 - test1
 test2

Row 3 - 
test1       test2
       test3

**Desired output**

Row 1 - test1

Row 2 - test2

Row 3 - test3

Why is the data aggregating? I suspect it has something to with the loop logic but haven't been able to fix it..

Any leads for rewriting the code to eliminate the aggregation are very much appreciated!!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update_Market_Status()

Dim d As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim prev_acts As String
Dim next_acts As String
Dim ws As Object
Dim status_report As Object
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim last_project As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project plan")
Set status_report = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status Report")
lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project plan").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
last_project = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status Report").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1

On Error Resume Next

    For j = 8 To last_project

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status Report").Range("C" & j).Value <> "" Then

        For d = 2 To lastRow

           If ws.Range("V" & d).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status Report").Range("I" & j).Value Then

            If LCase(ws.Range("N" & d).Value) = "y" Then

            If LCase(ws.Range("T" & d).Value) = "c" Then
                    If prev_acts = vbNullString Then
                        prev_acts = "'- " & ws.Range("D" & d).Value
                        Else
                        prev_acts = prev_acts & vbLf & "- " & ws.Range("D" & d).Value
                    End If

                ElseIf LCase(ws.Range("T" & d).Value) = "o" Or LCase(ws.Range("T" & d).Value) = vbNullString Then
                    If next_acts = vbNullString Then
                        next_acts = "'- " & ws.Range("D" & d).Value
                        Else
                        next_acts = next_acts & vbLf & "- " & ws.Range("D" & d).Value
                    End If
               End If
         End If
         End If

      Next d

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status Report").Range("E" & j).Value = prev_acts ' Previous Actions
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status Report").Range("F" & j).Value = next_acts ' Next Actions

    End If

    Next j

    End Sub
```

Comment: You never reset `prev_acts` or `next_acts` to a blank string for a new iteration.

Comment: That did the job, thanks @BigBen!